# Оптимизация вложенного SQL запроса

Tags: mysql

Всем привет и с наступившим Новым Годом!

Теперь к вопросу: имеется sql запрос

```
SELECT `tema`.*, 
   (SELECT Count(*) 
    FROM   `post` 
    WHERE  `post`.`id_tema` = `tema`.`id`) AS `count_post`, 
   (SELECT `id` 
    FROM   `post` 
    WHERE  `post`.`id_tema` = `tema`.`id` 
    ORDER  BY `id` DESC 
    LIMIT  1)  AS `id_post`, 
   (SELECT `login` 
    FROM   `users` 
    WHERE  `users`.`id` = (SELECT `id_user` 
                           FROM   `post` 
                           WHERE  `post`.`id_tema` = `tema`.`id` 
                           ORDER  BY `id` DESC 
                           LIMIT  1)
   )  AS `login` 
FROM   `tema` 
WHERE  `id_forum` = '4' 
ORDER  BY `up` DESC, `time` DESC 
LIMIT  3260, 20
```

Срок выполнения -  2.7 секунды.

Структура БД:

```
--
-- Структура таблицы `tema`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `tema`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tema` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_razdel` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_forum` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`translate` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`up` enum('0', '1') NOT NULL default '0',
`closed` enum('0', '1') NOT NULL default '0',
`count` int(11) NOT NULL default '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_razdel` (`id_razdel`),
KEY `id_forum` (`id_forum`),
KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
KEY `time` (`time`),
KEY `up` (`up`),
FULLTEXT KEY `name` (`name`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Структура таблицы `post`
--
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `post`;
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `post` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
`id_razdel` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_forum` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_tema` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_user` int(11) NOT NULL,
`text` text NOT NULL,
`cit` int(11) NOT NULL,
`time` int(11) NOT NULL,
`timeedit` int(11) NOT NULL,
`kedit` int(11) NOT NULL,
`id_user_edit` int(11) NOT NULL,
`vote` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `id_razdel` (`id_razdel`),
KEY `id_forum` (`id_forum`),
KEY `id_tema` (`id_tema`),
KEY `id_user` (`id_user`),
KEY `time` (`time`),
FULLTEXT KEY `text` (`text`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Explain запроса [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно вопрос: как можно оптимизировать данный sql запрос?

Comment: Чтоб помочь улучшить что-то, нужно знать что вы хотели получить/достичь. А вы этого самого главного и не написали.

Comment: Нужно получить кол-во постов к теме, id последнего поста и логин пользователя, оставившего последний пост.

Comment: Начал писать ответ, когда в вопросе, был только один вложенный select, пока писал - появилось еще два. ИМХО, проблема лечится только путем усекновения головы - денормализацией базы данных. Добавьте в таблицу вычисляемые поля, которые будут обновляться в момент добавления данных. Так будет намного быстрее

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов просто в начале было сообщение в oneline, а потом я его отформатировал, чтоб было видно весь запрос))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем сделал как и посоветовали.

В таблице tema добавил 3 поля: id_user_last, id_post_last, countpost. При добавлении нового поста они обновляются. При удалении также.

И сам запрос получился короче:

```
    SELECT `tema`.*,
     `users`.`login`
       FROM `tema` LEFT JOIN `users` ON `tema`.`id_user_last` = `users`.`id` 
        WHERE `id_forum`='4' ORDER BY `up` DESC, `time` DESC LIMIT 3260, 20
```

Работает в разы быстрее и при большем кол-ве данных.

Answer (score 1):

Не надо писать такие страшные запросы!

У вас есть отдельная таблица `tema` в которую заносите (соответствующие поля добавьте для этого) количество постов в теме, id последнего поста, id и логин юзера последнего поста и т.д. и т.п. при добавлении/удалении последнего поста темы. Так вы получите значительно меньшую нагрузку на базу.

P.S. Количество постов в теме еще при удалении любого поста в ней нужно будет изменить.

Comment: Visman, как вариант, но только вот логин может быть изменен, а будет отображаться старый.

Comment: @vitagame, кто мешает при изменении логина поменять его во всех таблицах где он используется? Или логин не сохраняйте в `tema`, только id юзера и через `JOIN` получайте его из таблицы юзеров. Это мизерная нагрузка.

Comment: с JOIN не дружу(

Comment: @vitagame, полистайте вопросы https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=mysql+JOIN